# Word for meaning across the solar system

Tags: single-word-requests, science, compound-words, obscure-terms

Is there a single term in english that means "to cross or to traverse a solar system"?

For crossing the Atlantic we have transatlantic, to cross the continent we have transcontinental and even to cross a galaxy we have trans-galactic (admittedly the last one is a hyphenate) But as far as I can tell we dont have any single word for traversing a solar-system.

My first instinct would be to say trans-solar-system. But, a double hyphenate feela awkward and the sound of it also seems incorrect.

My reason for asking is that I'm writing a paper describing satellite transfer paths that span the solar system and a single term would let my writing flow slightly better.

Comment: There are quite a few hits proposing "trans-solar-system" and "trans-solar system" on the Internet.

Comment: Most of the hits I found related to transsolar, which is a company out of Germany. I know that trans-solar and trans-solar-system have been used in a lot of previous writing but is there not a single term word, i.e. no hyphens for it?

Comment: *Interplanetary*, maybe.

Comment: When you've established the system in question, _system-wide_ will perhaps suffice. Though it really invokes a static rather than a travel situation.

Comment: Interplanetary is a good suggestion, but that implies that you're moving from one planet to another, whereas I'm planning a mission that hits multiple planets on the path. Multi-interplanetary perhaps?

Comment: @Diesel 'Interplanetary' works for multiple planets. Using 'Multi-interplanetary' is like eating goulash with your mouth open; that may be the way you do it when you're alone, but nobody else wants to be around you then.

Comment: Interplanetary space is what lies closer than interstellar space. The boundary is typically taken to be 12 billion miles out.

Comment: _Transsolar_ (_trans-solar_) is used in some [science fiction books](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&biw=1745&bih=990&tbm=bks&ei=twx5Xp3RCMODtQaPuYHgDQ&q=%22transsolar%22+space&oq=%22transsolar%22+space&gs_l=psy-ab.3...15586.17449.0.17530.12.12.0.0.0.0.94.948.12.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.88...33i10k1.0.6Zm_I8q_oGE) and astronomy related articles: [1](http://www.space4peace.org/ianus/npsm3.htm#kosmos198), [2](https://www.aol.com/article/2016/05/04/mercury-to-make-rare-pass-between-earth-and-sun-on-may-9/21370322/).

Comment: @Gustavson, It seems like "trans-solar system" would probably be the best hyphenation approach (at least under the APA - https://apastyle.apa.org/learn/faqs/when-use-hyphen), especially since "solar system" is generally not hyphenated by itself anyways.